# Colored coin in Ethereum to differentiate the wallet ether balance

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, ether, accounts

I have heard of the concept of colored coin in bitcoin , is there anything similar in Ethereum?

> I want to have a single wallet which maintains two types of ether

.
lets say one coming from me adding ether and other earning from playing games
.
i want to use these two ethers separately in a single wallet.
is there anything for this?

thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethereum was designed with this feature in mind, among others. You usually won't hear people call them "colored coins" but rather, tokens.

Try these links in the intro docs:

https://ethereum.org/token

https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/12/03/how-to-build-your-own-cryptocurrency/

Or if you just want code:

```
contract tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData); }

contract MyToken {
    /* Public variables of the token */
    string public standard = 'Token 0.1';
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function MyToken(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        uint8 decimalUnits,
        string tokenSymbol
        ) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
        totalSupply = initialSupply;                        // Update total supply
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
        decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
        msg.sender.send(msg.value);                         // Send back any ether sent accidentally
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;           // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
    }

    /* Allow another contract to spend some tokens in your behalf */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
        return true;
    }

    /* A contract attempts to get the coins */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;  // Check for overflows
        if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;   // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /* This unnamed function is called whenever someone tries to send ether to it */
    function () {
        throw;     // Prevents accidental sending of ether
    }
}
```

Comment: feeling very difficult to understand this.. any easy way to understand and implement? @koampapapa

Comment: Try the links I gave you. They are not that bad... just drink a coffee first

Comment: hahaha... I read those links, i couldn't install mist properly on my linux system ,it is making some problem. so i couldn't deploy any contracts so far and so stuck with running contracts part. so looking for something which is easy way to implement :D

Comment: Yea that also did not work for me on Linux. Then I found this awesome thing https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js
Then I continued through the tutorial and learned a lot. Then I had A.D.D. and didnt actually implement my contract, but I bet if you wanted to you could

Comment: yes i tried that but couldn't implement. i have installed truffle/pudding as well. but couldnot connect truffle with geth and struggling :(